# How does authentication work in MAPI/HTTP

Tags: http, authentication, mapi, outlook-2013

I am trying to understand how authentication in MAPI/HTTP protocol works. I read through the documents that `protocol supports basic authentication scheme, NT LAN Manager (NTLM) Authentication Protocol, and Negotiate` Ref MS-OXCMAPIHTTP#1.7.

So I have setup an Outlook365 account. While debugging (TLS session) I do see that server always asks for `WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=`. I did understand how does that work. But I fail to see any reference of `NTLM` or `Negotiate`. The document(s) does not provide any examples of either.

Online search is almost always fruitless about this topic.

I would appreciate some pointers or s'more documents or examples.

Answer (score 0):

In enterprise environments is most of the cases SPNEGO with Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

There's a registry of HTTP authentication schemes at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml, with pointers to specifications. (And yes, "NTLM" isn't registered; complain to Microsoft...).